# JavaScript scope (recursion) -- argument value overwritten by return value without explicit declaration

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

My first solution to an in order tree traversal worked off of the return value of the recursive function calls:

```
BST.prototype.inOrder = function(node, array){
   if(!node){ return []; }
   if(!array){ array = []; }

   return this.inOrder(node.left).concat([node.val], this.inOrder(node.right))

}
```

But then I saw that it can be also solved with the code below, and I am confused as to how the 'array' value is being persisted..

```
BST.prototype.inOrder = function(node, array){
  if(!node){ return []; }
  if(!array){ array = []; }
  this.inOrder(node.left, array);
  array.push(node.val);
  this.inOrder(node.right, array)
  return array
}
```

When the first recursive function call returns, is it overwriting the value of array within the scope of that function? Why is it doing that?

Comment: The array isn't 'overwritten', its mutated recursively until there's no more data.

Comment: So you're saying that operations performed on the array one level deeper are also performed on the array in the scope of the initial call?

Comment: Yes a reference to it is passed in the recursive call. Arrays in JavaScript (and many other languages) are reference types, they are not copied when you pass them as arguments to functions. Your focus on scope is barking up the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an overloaded function that would be called without a second argument in the first call, and in that case the variable is initialised with an empty array. A better way to write this might be

```
BST.prototype.appendInOrder = function(node, array) {
  if (!node) return;
  this.appendInOrder(node.left, array);
  array.push(node.val);
  this.appendInOrder(node.right, array);
}
BST.prototype.inOrder = function(node) {
  var array = [];
  this.appendInOrder(node, array);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so in essence you're passing the argument array so that these other scopes can have access to the same array in memory?

Comment: Yes, exactly, all objects (including arrays) are reference values. Passing the value to a function shares the reference to the mutable collection of properties in memory.